# About a solution of Measure Theory and Integration

Tags: integration, measure-theory

The problem is from Folland's book of Measure Theory and Integration. In this problem, $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is the measure space and $L^+$ is the space of measurable functions $f:X\to[0,\infty]$. The problem and the solution are showed below.

[image: fol]

I have just a little question about this solution. In this context, when we are talking about simple functions I always presume that we have something like $\Phi:X\to[0,\infty]$, that is, the domain is always $X$. Assuming this, it is necessary that $\bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i = X$, so the result is trivial, because $X\in\mathcal{M}$ and obviously $\int_X f d\mu > (\int_X f d\mu) - \varepsilon$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your question is not clear ! I don't see the correlation with the exercise. Of course that $X$ is measurable ! if not, the space $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ would have no sense ! But we are not talking about $X$ but about $E\subset X$ which is not necessarily measurable !

Comment: BTW: One can also solve the problem without using an approximation by simple functions. Show that $E_n = \{x \mid |f(x)| \geq 1/n\}$ has finite measure for each $n$ and that $\int_{E_n} f \to \int f$ (how?). This also gives the claim (why?).

Comment: @idm We could just take $E=X$ as a solution ($E\subset X$ includes the possibility of $E=X$). But as pointed in the answers, we could have $\mu(X) = \infty$.

Comment: I made a mistake when interpreting the definition of a simple function, that's all. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @PhoemueX I like your idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain of $\phi$ is $X$, but the sets $E_i$ need not partition $X$; they're just elements of $\mathcal{M}$. So the $E_i$ have nothing to do with $X$.

Answer (score 3):

The domain of $\phi$ is indeed $X$, but this does not mean that $\bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i=X$. Recall the definition of $\chi_{{}_{E_i}}$. It takes a value of $1$ at any $x\in E_i$ and takes a value of $0$ outside of $E_i$. The point here is that since $\int f<\infty$, we have $\int \phi<\infty$, so $\int a_i\chi_{{}_{E_i}}<\infty$ which gives us $\mu(E_i)<\infty$.

Note that the issue with your trivial solution is that $\mu(X)$ could be infinite (indeed, the hard part of the problem is getting a set of finite measure to do the trick).