# Measure Theory - Problem with definition about simple functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I did [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105537/about-a-solution-of-measure-theory-and-integration) question lately and then realized what my mistake was. I got a good help!
But looks like only now I understand what was the real problem, to begin with. And this brought me to the same questioning.

In the same (same used in the previous question) book of Measure theory and Integration of Folland, we have the following definition.

[image: def]

The definition of integration is made only for simple function with standard representation, and this is with a good reason, the text above says why. Therefore, to the purposes of integration, it is sufficient to consider only simple functions with standard representation in the definition of integral in $L^+$ ?

With this in mind, why couldn't we just consider $$\int f = \sup\Big\{ \int \Phi: \ 0\leq\Phi\leq f, \Phi \textrm{ is a simple and in standard representation}  \Big\}$$

instead $$\int f = \sup\Big\{ \int \Phi: \ 0\leq\Phi\leq f, \Phi \textrm{ is a simple}  \Big\}?$$

The last one is the "official" definition.

If we accept this, the answers I was given are wrong. So, I want (and need, this is too fundamental to just let alone) to know what is wrong with my reasoning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point that I think you're missing is that no matter how you represent a simple function, it's integral will be the same. This justifies the fact that it doesn't matter if the simple function is in its standard representation or not. That is, integrating a simple function is well-defined. The reason that this is even stressed is because there are infinitely many ways to represent the $\textit{same}$ simple function; so we need the integral to be the same no matter how it's represented. For example, if $\phi(x) = \chi_{(0,1]}(x) + \chi_{(1,2]}(x) = \chi_{(0,2]}(x)$, then the integrals (with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$) are the same:
$$\int \phi(x) dm = m((0,1]) + m((1,2]) = 1 + 1 = 2 = m((0,2]) = \int \phi(x) dm$$

Putting a simple function in its standard representation is useful when you're proving things for simple functions. For instance, when proving the integral is additive for simple functions, it is best that the sets $E_i$ are disjoint.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't matter if the simple function is in its standard representation or not, we will have the same thing. And that is my point, it doesn't matter so I can use only standard representation and get the same results. There is no problem working only with standard representations. But when assuming this the argument from the previous question doesn't work anymore, and it means that this equivalent definition can't be used in the same proof. It looked weird to me.

Comment: You can consider only standard representations, but adding that into the definition of the integral of a non-negative function is unnecessary because of the above. In practice, you don't often find the standard representation for a specific function to do calculations, you use the standard representation to aid you in proving things about general functions.

Comment: @Integral: **Every** simple function **has** a standard representation. It does not make sense to say that a simple function $\Phi$ **is** in standard representation. You can also not say something like "let $x$ be a real number in base $2$ expansion" (it makes no sense). Every real number has such an expansion. It only makes sense to write "let $0.b_1 b_2 \dots$ be the binary expansion of $x$". Likewise,it makes sense to say "let $\sum a_i \chi_{A_i}$ be the standard representation of $\Phi$". This is just one particular way of writing $\Phi$.