# Detail in Definition of Simple Functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory

The motivation to this question comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108464/measure-theory-problem-with-definition-about-simple-functions), but it's not necessary to see the link to understand my question.

In the book of Measure Theory and integration of Folland, we have the following definition for simple functions and their standard representation.

[image: def]

If $f$ is simple but not in standard representation we may have $f = \sum_{i=1}^nz_i\mathcal{X}_{E_i}$ such that $\cup_{i=1}^nE_i\neq X$. In this case, how do I deal with the elements $x\in X\backslash(\cup_{i=1}^nE_i)$ ? Looks like $f(x)$ is not defined for this elements, but this is nonsense because there is a standard representation $g = \sum_{i=1}^my_i\mathcal{X}_{F_i}$ such that $f=g$ and $\cup_{i=1}^mF_i = X$, so $X$ is the domain of $f$ (for $X$ is the domain of $g$), this looks like a contradiction.

What is going on here?

Comment: Characteristic functions are defined everywhere.  The values are either $1$ or $0$.  A finite linear combination of them is also defined everywhere.  For $x\in X\backslash(\cup_{i=1}^nE_i)$, every term of the sum has value $0$ so the sum has value $0$.  Value $0$ is not the same as "undefined".

Comment: So why the author said that the union $\cup_{i=1}^nE_i$ is $X$ for the standard representation and didn't say the same for only simple functions? It's not clear why $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i\mathcal{X}_{E_i}$ should include values in $X\backslash(\cup_{i=1}^nE_i)$ if $\cup_{i=1}^nE_i \neq X$. It's not said in the text that characteristic functions are defined everywhere.

Comment: Folland is saying that you can think about $X \setminus(\cup_i E_i)$ as part of the standard rep by adding the term $0 \cdot \chi_{X\setminus(\cup_i E_i)}$ to your sum. Every characteristic function is defined everywhere. $\chi_E(x) =1$ if $x \in E$ and $\chi_{E}(x) = 0$ if $x \notin E$.

Comment: You are right, thank you!